# Configuration Management and SlowCheetah

Tags: configurationmanager, slowcheetah

I need to apply **xdt transformations** to other files than ***.config** ones.
I found the SlowCeetah extension which seems to provide this kind of feature as authors and extension page says, but, even if I setup the trasformation for xml files, and note that the 
**preview tool** works well.., according to solution configuration manager configuratoins, no
transformation is applied.

For example I setup the trasformation for log4net.xml file, by using the tooling command "Add Transformation" which added log4net.*{configname}*.xml files but nothing happen when I deploy the solution or simply build with the specific build configuration.

Anyone has seen this issue?

Googlin' around I found that trasnformations to xml files should be applied to files setup as Content and Copy Always, anyone has suggestion about that?

I 'm very sad becaues I made all my configurations with transformations, and if I cannot solve that issue I lost 2 days of boring config job and I just can do that manually
Thanks in advance
Cheers

Comment: Could you try with the latest version and let me know if you have any issues. This should now be working.